# Is there a way to set a minimum time between consecutive keystrokes of the same key on a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

My MacBook keyboard is water damaged and now whenever I type a space it often registers two, and sometime even 3 keystrokes. Just typing this question is quite infuriating as I have to constantly go back and delete spaces. A hardware fix is not really possible so I was wondering if there is a software fix for this. I am thinking if I could set a minimum time between consecutive keystrokes it should fix the problem without affecting my typing experience adversely.

Comment: Quick check. If you hold a fully-functional key, for instance 'a' for a few seconds, then do you get repetition or the "pick an accent" floater, with åàä etc? If your keyboard is actually rapidly re-transmitting the same key, I don't think there is a way to change that. Accessibility's slow keys is kind of the opposite of that.

Comment: @Tetsujin It goes to the 'pick an accent' floater.

Comment: Not ideal, but you should be able to use a separate keyboard connecting either by USB or Bluetooth.

Comment: Look under Accessibility options.